# Missing Grant Type in Post method In Android

Tags: android, json, api, postman

While using `Post` method In Android my `grant type` in Missing

I want to acess_token from my post method but it show grant_type missing because in body my grant_type is client_credentials so how can i add grant_type to my url so i give permission to access_token

```
 Request originalRequest = chain.request();

 String credentials = authUserName + ":" + authPassword;

 final String basic =Base64.encodeToString(credentials.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);

 Request newRequest = chain.request().newBuilder().addHeader("Authorization","Basic  " + basic).build();
                    return chain.proceed(newRequest);
```

**My `apiInterface`**

```
@POST("token")
Call<ResponseBody> getToken();
```

}

**My Log report**

```
D/OkHttp: {"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"Missing grant type"}
```

**Postman Post method Screen shot**

[image]

[image]

How can i grant_type in my code

Answer (score 1):

```
 String credentials = authUserName + ":" + authPassword;
                    final String basic = Base64.encodeToString(credentials.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
                    RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"), "grant_type=client_credentials");
                    Request newRequest = chain
                            .request()
                            .newBuilder()
                            .addHeader(HTTP_AUTH_HEADER, "Basic  " + basic)
                            .addHeader("Content_Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                            .post(body).build();
```

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you trying to do. From the code it seems that you are using OAuth2 to Authenticate inside your application
So please post the complete url which is being formed at the end before sending the request.
When using OAuth2 you need to pass the parameter `grant_type` and `redirect URL` that is configured into the server when you register your application in the authentication server. The grant type can have possible values like `code` or `implicit`
Good luck

Comment: I want to acess_token from my post method but it show grant_type missing because in body my grant_type is client_credentials so how can i add grant_type to my url so i give permission to access_token